# MySQL databases CSV file and conception

Tags: database-design, csv

I have some trouble with the conception of my databases model.

I have a big CSV files for the category of the future website.

```
BIGCAT1;SUBCAT1;SUBSUBCAT1;BRAND1
BIGCAT1;SUBCAT1;SUBSUBCAT2;BRAND2
BIGCAT2;SUBCAT2;SUBSUBCAT3;BRAND1
BIGCAT2;SUBCAT2;SUBSUBCAT4;BRAND3
```

As you can see, a SUBCATx belongs only for a BIGCATx. A SUBSUBCATx belongs only for a SUBCATx. But a BRANDx can belong for more than one SUBSUBCAT.

At the start, I create an CSV parser... and I counsider each BRAND like a subsubsub...cat. It works, but it's so revolting. If I treat each brand like a category, I have 3,600 brands... when I remove duplicates, I have only 2,106 unique Brand... (+/-1,500 duplicates).

If I think my database model with relation category (id,is_active) / category_has_brand (category.id, brand.id) / brand (id, is_active) : How can I work with a CSV file for generating my database insertions ?

And because it is fun... it's multilingual (for BIGCAT,SUBCAT,SUBSUBCAT but not for BRAND).

If I fill by hand this database... it's OK. But i don't want to do that.

Is anyone have an idea ? I use PHP and MySQL for read my file and fill my database.

Is there a way to use this kind of CSV to generate entries in 3 SQL tables : category (id,is_active) / category_has_brand (category.id, brand.id) / brand (id, is_active) ?

Regards

Comment: It would help if you asked a specific question, or at least defined the criteria for an "idea" you might receive.

Comment: Why are your fields separated by semicolons instead of commas?

Comment: it's just a separator. It's not important. The only question is "is there a way to use this kind of CSV to generate entries in 3 SQL tables : category (id,is_active) / category_has_brand (category.id, brand.id) / brand (id, is_active) ?

Comment: Are you absolutely certain (yeah, right) that you will always have just 3 levels, i.e.: Category, Subcategory, SubSubCategory?

Comment: I recieve the new file there is few minutes and... no, sometimes there is 2 lvls and no brand... and sometimes 5 level. The last column of a line is not always a brand. So fun T____T

Comment: You have to impose some structure, especially because tree-like structures with variable nesting levels are usually problematic in SQL. Can you create a dummy "sub-sub-category" for the missing subcategories? and use "null" for the missing brand? What about the 5-levels records?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you're asking two questions:

- How should I structure my database?
- How should I import my CSV file?

The database design can be pretty simple:

```
Category
-----------
CategoryID
ParentCategoryID
```

This is based on the "subcategories only belong to a single parent" statement. If it turns out to be "many to many", you need to create a joining table instead of ParentGategoryID.

To store localized category descriptions etc, you can have a localized string table:

```
CategoryDescription
------------
CategoryID
Locale
Description
```

From what you write, there's a "many to many" between category and brand, so that would work as follows:

```
Brand
-----
BrandID
.... 

CategoryBrand
---------
CategoryID
BrandID
```

I don't think there's a neat way of importing the CSV file. The pseudo code might be:

```
for each line in CSV file
  for each field in line
     if field is category
          add category if not exists
          if category is not top level
              set category Parent to last category
          end if
     end if
     if field is brand
         add brand if not exists
         set brand category to last category
     end if
   next field
 next line
```

Answer (score 0):

I would create 3 tables for Cat/Subcat/SubSubcat.

```
CatId | Description | Whatever else fits there, like "active flag".
```

...

```
SubCatId | Description | Whatever else fits there, like "active flag".
```

...

```
SubSubCatId | Description | Whatever else fits there, like "active flag".
```

then a Brand table:

...

```
BrandId | Name | Description | Whatever else fits there, like "Country Iso Code".
```

then I would create a "Triplet+Brand" structure with foreigh keys to the 3 tables:

```
CatId|SubcatId|SubSubCatId|BrandId
```

Now your CSV import becomes:

```
Read a record from CSV
   Split it into Cat/Subcat/SubSubCat/Brand - these will all be descriptions, or names
   Find if the the Category exists, if yes get ID from DB, otherwise create Category table and generate Id by sequence
   Find SubCategory (as above)
   ...
   Find Brand (as above)
   Create record with  CatId+SubcatId+SubSubCatId+BrandId
```

Using appropriate unique keys you will also avoid duplicates both during creation or later in the lifecycle of the application.